# Remove multiple words from textfile

Tags: notepad++

I've created a program that uses a games API to check word lists in regards to the userbase and returns a list of words that don't currently exist.

I have a list of about 14,000 words and another list of about 500 words that haven't been taken by the userbase.

I want to take the list of 500 words > match it with my list of 14,000 words and remove these 500 from that 14,000 wordlist.

So, when I go to rerun my list of 14,000 words, all of the junk names will have been removed and I can see new results IF new results happen to appear.

I have yet to find a method or expression to remove multiple lines of different text that appears in another set of text.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: When you mentioned about your code that interacts with the API, what language are you specifically referring to? As it stands it’s hard to write any code that solve your problem in a tangible, meaningful manner.

Comment: C#, but i prefer to use N++ outside of the program and just remove the junk from the testlist

Comment: What about merging the two files first and then deleting duplicate lines using a RegEx `^(.*?)$\s+?^(?=.*^\1$)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: that wouldn't work @help-info.de

removing the duplicate doesn't also remove the original, so this doesn't benefit me here.